# How to debug a Spring Thymelieaf page Spring security

Tags: java, spring, security, thymeleaf

I'm new to Thymeleaf, but worked with JSPs before, so that should be the same principle I would have thought.

Anyhow... I'm trying to put together the following Spring security tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/.

It uses Thymeleaf for the frontend page rendering, and the following Login page does not play ball:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Invalid username and password.
</div>
<form th:action="@{/login.html}" method="post">
    <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I have the following Spring security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/greeting").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html", true)
            .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

The page with the form displays just fine, but when I provide the above credentials (user/password), it does not log the user in. It basically gets stuck in a loop demanding to login; there is a homepage.html, but it's never redirected to.

There is nothing in the logs, no errors or any messages.

Trying to debug it, I've added the following controller:

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class GreetingController {

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name = "username", value = "xxx") String username, @RequestParam(name = "password", value = "yyy") String password, Model model) {
        log.info("U " + username + " P " + password);
        model.addAttribute("username", username);
        model.addAttribute("password", password);

        return "login";
    }
}
```

but when trying to invoke `http://localhost:8080/login`, I get the following error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

So, having tried all above, I'm kinda stuck now and not sure what to try next.

How do I debug such a login page to find out what's going on? Also, could anyone spot any problems with the code I've provided above so far?

Comment: Your form should post to `/login` not `/login.html`, nor should you have a controller as the login is handled by Spring Security **not** your controller.

Comment: Yeah, perfect, you're right - `/login` works, and I don't need the controller.